# How to replace angular2-template-loader in Webpack 5 with ts-loader

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack-5, ts-loader

I've inherited a Webpack4 Angular 11 lerna bootstrap repo, and I'd like to get us on Webpack5 (as well as workspaces etc.)

This repo uses angular2-template-loader with ts-loader and fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin.

angular2-template-loader does not work with webpack5 and the only replacement I've found has been @ngtools/webpack, but that requires replacing ts-loader and fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin. Our build is slow enough as is, and I'm worried @ngtools/webpack will be even slower as well as requiring a painful migration adding the new plugin everywhere with configuration unique to every sub-project in the monorepo.

So, has anyone managed to replace the functionality of angular2-template-loader in webpack5 while retaining ts-loader?

Comment: Just wanted to follow up that I've _tried_ to port packages to angular-cli, but it is so much more strict (even with all of the strictness turned off) than our current system that it would take hundreds-thousands of man hours to fix, and I highly suspect some new blocker would show up after I did that. So dear readers, saying stuff like "just use foo instead" is not the mic drop you think it is

Answer (score -1):

[Based on a Quick Internet search, Angular 12 CLI uses Webpack 5.](https://giancarlobuomprisco.com/angular/webpack-5-angular12)

> Angular 12 has been released and with it the much awaited Webpack 5 upgrade.

If your project does not use the Angular CLI, I strongly recommend converting it to Angular CLI project.

If your project does use the Angular CLI; then just upgrade, [using these instructions](https://update.angular.io/?v=11.0-12.0).  I recommend upgrading all the way to the current version of Angular.

Comment: yeah, no angular2-template-loader isn't from the Angular team, it's a webpack loader that inlines things like styleUrls, templateUrls etc. @ngtools/webpack is from the Angular team, but can't be used with any other typescript loader and requires quite a bit of tedium to use (assuming I can even figure out how to shoehorn it into my current system). Also webpack is completely blackboxed by angular-cli, so if you use webpack loaders, you inherently don't use angular-cli

Comment: Just for added context... Upgrading Webpack from 4 to 5 is not a trivial endeavor, webpack builds often rely on 3rd party loaders and plugins that become incompatible with the latest version and the methods of replacing those loaders/plugins are not always obvious or straightfoward

Comment: Then I'll repeat my first recommendation to migrate the project to an Angular CLI project.  Angular CLI is mature enough that it isn't worth the development effort to roll your own.

Comment: that might be true, but not the question I asked and tone deaf to the reality of dealing with legacy projects with arcane status quo... And Angular only just now added _experimental_ support for Jest over Karma. That's not mature, that's like an 18 year old at best

Comment: You're dealing with a project on Angular 11; which is not old enough to be considered legacy.  Odd that such a project would not be already on the Angular CLI.  
There are projects out there to use JEST with the Angular CLI.  But, I've never had a problem w/ Karma that warranted exploring them.  
Good Luck!